# How to send command to a running program and get result from it?

Tags: c#, windows

I've an application same as command line application. I type command, it send command to server and display result on screen.
My application is an executable application on windows and has two feature that help me to easy work: record script and play script.
Now, I want to send command to running application and raise play script button to run sent command on it.
Is there any way to solve this problem in c# language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793997/pass-arguments-to-running-application

Answer (score 0):

Uh-oh. I hope I understood you correctly. I assume you have a third-party application that interacts with some server and is operated by two distinct commands, play and record. You want to write a new application that would invoke these commands somehow, and the problem is this invocation.

You can do it in C#, but the way you do it depends on the way you operate the program. I will show you some cases:

- The program is a command line tool. Input is sent via command line parameters when the program is run. Output is gathered via redirections of the standard output of the program. Look at `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` and its parameters, namely `ProcessStartInfo` which contains parameters and input/output redirection options.
- The program is a console tool that is not operated via command line parameters. Use the same as above, but feed input via input redirection.
- The program is a GUI program with no ability to get input in text form. This is most likely the case. Here you will have to either find a specific way to operate the program such as with an advanced technique called hooking. Or you can send commands as if a user is issuing them. Look at `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` method. It might help. How to get a result here is a big question. You can either parse the screen or monitor some state of a program or something else. No ready solution for everyone here.

Comment: Thank for your response Aneri, I'm succeed to start an exe application in c# and send key or character to it same as Calculator.exe and notepad.exe. But I've an application which I can not send any key or this doesn't have any behavior. How I can know about my application for this capability for transact with c# application?