# Limit to one instance and communication between instances

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm making my own imageviewer and want to limit to one instance and also be able to tell the instance already running to open the files attempted opened by the new instance.

I found code on this site to limit the program to one instance, but I haven't been able to find a solution for communication.

Comment: Looks it was already answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793997/pass-arguments-to-running-application
it should help you

Answer (score -1):

You could do this by calling a method to change the image source instead of attempting to create a new instance of the object :)

Comment: it's not an object, it's the application itself. Am I allowed to link to my files?

Comment: Apologies I misread :) and link to the files in what sense?

Comment: I'm making myself an imageviewer and wants to open all files with the same instance instead of having several programs running that shows different pictures