# Pass argument to running Unity game

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to pass a parameter to a running game by starting it again?

For a 'normal' application I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794293/3636680).

Does Unity have a feature to allow notification of another instance being started with parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "built-in solution" for that. What you can do is:
a) Set up your game so it can run in one instance only (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player)

[image: Forced Single Instance in Unity 5]

-or-
b) As soon as you start, read a [Player Setting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html), let's say a bool called "Running". If true, check if your app really is running with [GetProcessesByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx) (if it doesn't, your app hang up before). If it's "false", set it to "true" (and back to false when one [quits the game](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html))

As of "passing a value", that works with "b" option only obviously. I would also use `Player Settings` for that:
if game is already running, write a value (e.g. under an "inputparam" key) and quit. Otherwise run (i.e. keep running) and check this setting's value every now and then, every frame or once a minute, whenever, depending on how critical it is for you to get the input value.

---

Edit after a long while and some testing:
`GetProcessesByName` has proven to be quite unreliable with the unity. I ended up writing to the `PlayerPref` on startup and checking for that value.

Comment: Option B it is then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

People in their review of the [Google Sheets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15570) game asset say that they can modify a game at runtime.

> Great dev, and asset works at runtime!
>   ...
>   Super fast response and documentation update. Couldn't ask for more. Crucially works at runtime...