# Passing command line arguments to already running instance of my application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ipc

I would like to pass command line arguments of a new instance of my application to one already running (if one exists). So far, I have tried the following:

**Program.cs**

```
string[] Arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

int iCurrentProcessID = -1;
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, Arguments[1], out createdNew)) //Finding if application is running or not
{
    Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    iCurrentProcessID = current.Id;
    if (createdNew)
    {
        Application.Run(Frm1);
    }
    else
    {           
        //  Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process CurrentAutomation = Process.GetProcessById(iCurrentProcessID);

        string[] strArguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strArguments[2]))
        {
            frmMain.strEndtime = strArguments[2];              
        }
```

**Form.cs**

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public static string strEndtime;
    //...
}
```

Values are set correctly in the second instance, but are not set in the first (started earlier) one. How do I pass those values to the other instance of my application?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? do you want to set the first application instance's property value to argument of the second instance?

Comment: I want to use the second instance agrument in first instance.

Comment: try googling something like "c# pass parameters to running application", for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793997/pass-arguments-to-running-application) might help

Comment: I applied all but How can I use arguments thats what I want to know

Comment: you cannot simply pass values between processes. you have to implement special handling for that, which is relatively easy in winforms, fortunately. do your research in this topic - it has nothing to do with mutexes

Comment: I didn't got so posted here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133255/discussion-between-babu-and-slawekwin).

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can utilize WCF to send values between processes. Your main application expose a WCF service via net.pipe. Check this [link](https://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/) for details